# How to disable right click during navigation from one web page to other?

Tags: right-click

I have disabled right click by adding the following code. However, when I navigate from one page to other, during that window of time, on right click, the right click menu is opening.

```
document.onmousedown = function (event)
{
     event = (event || window.event);
     if (event.button == 2 )
     {

           alert("right click");
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind to elaborate why you have this requirement and in what context you are working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use oncontextmenu for this:

```
document.oncontextmenu = function () {return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen for case if document.onmousedown = function (event) isn't yet executed for some reason. Among reasons can be errors in java script or browser yet didn't execute document.onmousedown = function (event) because it is in process of executing some other javascript code.

Another proposal for consideration can be another way of disabling:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
```